# On Hadoop installation, bash: gives an 'is a directory error'

Tags: command-line, java, bashrc, hadoop, hive

When I run the command:

```
$ $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
```

it gives me the following error:

```
bash: /etc/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop: Is a directory
```

These are the contents of my .bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then


    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/etc/hadoop-2.7.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/conf

export DERBY_HOME=/usr/local/derby
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar
```

Comment: Why are you running that command? Did you read it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, the file you're trying to run, `/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop` is not an executable file, it is a directory. The error from bash is telling you that you can't execute a directory.

There is probably a file inside the `/etc/hadoop-2.7.1` directory that you need to run instead, probably `/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop`.

You could change your command to:

```
$ $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
```

Comment: I am guessing the OP wants `/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop`.

Comment: I was just scanning the docs to see where this would be, thanks @terdon

Comment: I don't know either, I am just assuming because the OP shows that `/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/` in added to their `$PATH`.

Comment: If it's in their path they should be able to just use `hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp` I'm guessing.

Comment: Yes,that issue got solved, Thanks @terdon  But now when i use the command  $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir  /tmp it is giving me the error:
mkdir: Call From Laddu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: the command $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp gives the following error: 
mkdir: Call From Laddu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: There is either nothing listening on port 9000 or your firewall is blocking that port. If you're using `ufw` the `ufw status` command will show which ports are allowed through the firewall.